# Do not show the web part of the SPList in SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I have a programmatically created SPList with custom content type and it is added to the quick launch.  Every time I click on the link on the quick launch, the page appears with a web part that shows the content of the list.

I do not want that... I wanted the web part gone so when I visit the page, there is no web part on it at all.  Is there any ways of doing this programmatically?  I do not want to have to manually delete the web part.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify false for "on quick launch" in the list definition, or from code, if you don't want to have the list view page link in quick launch. Why not just create a web-part page without the list view web-part on it, and add a link to that page to quick launch? Do you need to change the allitems page?

Comment: Yeah looks like there is no way of removing the document library content if I add it as a web part.  I wanted the document library to still be available on the quick launch, but upon clicking on it it will display a web part page without the default web part which displays the document library's documents.  I guess I will have to create a separate page for that.